# Android: How to pass a touchEvent (onClick) from a view in foreground to another view in background?

Tags: android, onclick, ontouchlistener, children

I am develepoing a PDF Reader app and want the user to be able to change the screen brightness with a swipe gesture.
For this I am using a toolbar with two views in it (a simple view for the swipe gesture and a ConstraintLayout with its child views that represents the toolbar).

The swipe gesture is working great but the problem is - because the view vSwipeGesture is above the cLayToolBar view - I can't use the toolbar views in background.

So my question is how to pass the onClick events throught my foreground (vSwipeGesture) to the views in background like imgGoToSite, imgNightMode...?

[image]

**toolbar layout**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/cLayContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/vSwipeGesture"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:translationZ="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/cLayToolbar"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cLaySearch"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtToolbarTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Zu letzt geöffnet..."
                        android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lLayTools"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="4"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtToolbarTitle"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgGoToSite"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_swap_horiz_black_24dp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgNightMode"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_wb_sunny_white_24dp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgDelete"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_outline_delete_24px" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgMore"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more_vert_white_24dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/cLaySearch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                        android:id="@+id/searchView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:iconifiedByDefault="true"
                        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                        android:searchHintIcon="@null"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:queryBackground="@drawable/search_background"
                        app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
                        app:theme="@style/SearchViewStyle">
                    </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**OnGestureRegisterListener**

```
public abstract class OnGestureRegisterListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private View view;

    public OnGestureRegisterListener(Context context) {
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        this.view = view;
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public abstract void onSwipeRight(View view);
    public abstract void onSwipeLeft(View view);
    public abstract void onSwipeBottom(View view);
    public abstract void onSwipeTop(View view);
    public abstract boolean onClick(View view);
    public abstract boolean onLongClick(View view);

    private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            onLongClick(view);
            super.onLongPress(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            onClick(view);
            return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {

                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight(view);
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft(view);
                        }
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom(view);
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop(view);
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
OnGestureRegisterListener onGestureRegisterListener = new OnGestureRegisterListener(this) {
    public void onSwipeRight(View view) {
        //CHANGE BRIGHTNESS -
    }
    public void onSwipeLeft(View view) {
        //CHANGE BRIGHTNESS +
    }
    public void onSwipeBottom(View view) {
        // Do something
    }
    public void onSwipeTop(View view) {
        // Do something
    }
    public boolean onClick(View view) {
        // Do something
        return false;
    }
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        // Do something
        return true;
    }
};

vSwipeGesture.setOnTouchListener(onGestureRegisterListener);

imgMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showPopupMenu(v, true, R.style.MyPopupStyle);
    }
});

imgGoToSite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        DialogHelper.showDialogGoToSite(MainActivity.this, pdfView);
    }
});
```